# PhpStorm, Yii2 Basic and Codeception

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm, codeception, yii2-basic-app

I have configuration:

- Open Server 5.2.8 (WAMP)
- PhpStorm 2017.3.4
- Yii 2.0.14 basic

I added to the `%PATH%` path to PHP and to the Codeception folder:
[image: Path to PHP]
[image: Path to Codeception]

In the PhpStorm terminal I launched the `codecept run` command and everything looks good. But the Windows terminal does not maintain colors therefore I wanted to launch tests through PhpStorm.

[image: PhpStorm Terminal]

I made such settings for PHPUnit and Codeception (from Yii2\vendor):

[image: PHPUnit Settings]

[image: Codeceptiont Settings]

But for some reason I receive such error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059726/phpstorm-v2017-3-4-codeception-v2-4-0-incompatibility) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40950). Thanks to @panosru.
Just download new version PHPStorm 2017.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the dependency for `phpunit`, add the following to your `composer.json`

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

and run

```
composer update
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/40OXQJJX3TVbNd), but the result is the same...

Comment: that is strange, can you confirm once after running `composer self-update` @SET

Comment: Yes, I can [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/_6SfyG9w3TVcvz). Maybe my mistake is in PHPStorm settings?

Comment: i think it was already there otherwise it should have been at the end  in the list